# Cannot install Synaptic (Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: synaptic

I have been trying to install Synaptic from both the Ubuntu Software Centre and the Terminal.

When I do it from the Software Centre it says:

```
synaptic: Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14) but 2.19-0ubuntu6.4 is to be installed
          Depends: libept1.4.12 but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1) but 1:4.9.1-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
          Depends: libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 (>= 2.22.0) but 2.30.7-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
          Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.14.0) but 2.40.2-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
          Depends: libgtk-3-0 (>= 3.0.0) but 3.10.8-0ubuntu1.4 is to be installed
          Depends: libpango-1.0-0 (>= 1.14.0) but 1.36.3-1ubuntu1.1 is to be installed
          Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.6) but 4.8.2-19ubuntu1 is to be installed
          Depends: libvte-2.90-9 (>= 1:0.27.2) but 1:0.34.9-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
```

And when I do it from terminal it says:

```
 synaptic : Depends: libept1.4.12 but it is not installable
        Recommends: libgtk2-perl (>= 1:1.130) but it is not installable
        Recommends: rarian-compat but it is not installable
        E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How can I fix this problem?

Any help would be appreciated.

Joe

Comment: Run sudo apt-get update and try again.

Comment: I've tried that with no success

Comment: Perhaps try `sudo apt-get install -f synaptic`

Comment: what error you are getting after executing `sudo apt-get install  libept1.4.12` ?

Comment: I am being told: Package libept1.4.12 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libept1.4.12' has no installation candidate

Answer (score 0):

It says that you have broken packages, so I would attempt to fix that first before trying to install Synaptic using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

After that is a success then I would try installing Synaptic

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

Comment: I am getting the same error as in my original post

Comment: What happens if you do a:   sudo apt-get dist-upgrade